# how to get the index of an array using the value in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $interests[50] = array('fav_beverages' => "beer");
?>
```

now i need the index (i.e. 50 or whatever the index may be) from the value `beer`.

I tried `array_search()`, `array_flip()`, `in_array()`, `extract()`, `list()` to get the answer.

please do let me know if I have missed out any tricks for the above functions or any other function I`ve not listed. Answers will be greatly appreciated.

thanks for the replies. But for my disappointment it is still not working. btw I have a large pool of data like  "beer");
    $interests[50] = array('fav_cuisine' => "arabic");
    $interests[50] = array('fav_food' => "hummus");  ?>      . my approach was to get the other data like "arablic" and "hummus" from the user input "beer". So my only connection is via the index[50].Do  let me know if my approach is wrong and  I can access the data through other means.My senior just informed me that I`m not supposed to use loop.

Comment: `var_dump(array_search(array('fav_beverages' => 'beer'), $interests, true));`

Comment: Why doesn't array_search work for you? `$index = array_search('beer', $interests);` will set the value of `$index` to the key index. http://uk3.php.net/array_search `array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful`

Comment: thanks for the replies. But for my disappointment it is still not working. btw I have a large pool of data like <?php
    $interests[50] = array('fav_beverages' => "beer");
    ?>

Comment: @PeeHaa the output is bool(false).

Answer (score 2):

This should work in your case.

```
$interests[50] = array('fav_beverages' => "beer");

function multi_array_search($needle, $interests){
    foreach($interests as $interest){
        if (array_search($needle, $interest)){
            return array_search($interest, $interests);
            break;
        }
    }
}

echo multi_array_search("beer", $interests);
```

Comment: You're calling `array_search()` twice. This might make it slower for large arrays. It could be improved by doing the assignment inside the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If your array contains multiple sub-arrays and you don't know which one contains the value `beer`, then you can simply loop through the arrays, and then through the sub-arrays, to search for the value, and then return the index if it is found:

```
$needle = 'beer';

foreach ($interests as $index => $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        if ($value == $needle) {
            echo $index;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/132572)

Comment: Exactly what I'm going to answer. +1